# How to prove that the subgroup generated by $\{-\log r_i\}_{i=1}^m$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, group-theory

Let $r_1,\ldots, r_m\in (0,1)$ be $m$ real numbers. If $\frac{\log r_i}{\log r_j}$ is irrational for some $i\not=j$, then the subgroup generated by $\{-\log r_i\}_{i=1}^m$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. How to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any subgroup of $(\mathbb R ,+)$ is either $\{0\}$ dense or it is of the type $\{nx: n \in \mathbb Z\}$ for some $x>0$. If our subgroup is of the last type then $\frac {\log r_i} t$ is an integer for all $i$. So $\frac {\log r_i} {\log r_j}$ is rational whenever $i \neq j$. Ref.: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Real_Numbers_is_Discrete_or_Dense

Comment: Incidentally, you forgot the trivial subgroup

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you very much.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy   Thank you very much!